# div not updating correctly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm hoping as I type out this question I'm going to see something obvious I missed, but just in case...

I did something similar to this a year ago, and it works great on another site, and i went line for line on code, but for some reason this time it isn't working. The behavior should be when I click on a link, it will load a div with external content, instead, it is going to the root of my site like http://www.example.com/#internet-div

Here is the code I am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#all-insights-link").click(function(){
        $("#all-div").load("/insights-category-divs/all-categories-tab");
    });
    $("#internet-insights-link").click(function(){
        $("#internet-div").load("/insights-category-divs/internet-tab");
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li><a href="#all-div" id="all-insights-link" class="-active">All Categories</a></li>
<li><a href="#internet-div" id="internet-insights-link">Internet</a></li>
</ul>


<!-- All categories -->
<div id="all-div">
              
all categories content to load on initial page, will disappear when "Internet" link is clicked
              
</div><!-- / #All categories -->
                    
<!-- Internet -->
<div id="internet-div">
              
</div><!-- / #Internet -->
```

Comment: can you see that the request is being made in your debugger?

Comment: Have you noted that the relative path must be relative to your loading script's location, not the location of the page you are loading to?

Comment: the href in the href will changes your url when they are clicked, to prevent that, you need to call `event.preventDefault()` inside the click handler

Comment: Thank you very much, I just added the event.preventDefault(), and I now see that the correct request is being made. It still isn't loading the div, but at least I'm not being put back in site root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anthony C was correct in the comments, I needed to add event.preventDefault() to my code, and make sure it appied only to that class. Final code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".-categories a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
$("#all-insights-link").click(function(){
    $("#show-content-div").load("/insights-category-divs/all-categories-tab");
});
$("#internet-insights-link").click(function(){
    $("#show-content-div").load("/insights-category-divs/internet-tab");
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`"/insights-category-divs/all-categories-tab"` and `"/insights-category-divs/all-categories-tab"` don't reach a file because there is no file extension and `.load()` requires a file. It should read something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#all-insights-link").click(function(){
        $("#all-div").load("/insights-category-divs/all-categories-tab.html");
    });
    $("#internet-insights-link").click(function(){
        $("#internet-div").load("/insights-category-divs/internet-tab.php");
    });

});
```

Comment: In this case, it is actually getting a 200 response in chrome network tab, and in the preview window I am seeing the correct content that should go in that div, but this is what I thought at first and did try it with the file extensions